# Run .exe with C# Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have the following set up:

```
namespace TSRVTC_GUI
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnselect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fdb = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fdb.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            txtpath.Text = fdb.SelectedPath;
    }

    private void btnlaunch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"fdb\Launcher.exe");
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to start a program contained within a different directory to the .exe but this doesn't work, if someone could help me I'd appreciate it.

I also apologize for the back structure of this question but I am still new on here.

Comment: you would need to specify the full path

Comment: the path would be what the user selects with is stored in 'fdb'

Comment: don't you have the path in `textPath.Text` for the exe?

Comment: I do but since I'm just creating this for a gaming community, each person's path will be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Text` property of `txtpath` instance of `TextBox` as you are setting the Path in it from `FolderBrowseDialog` instance, you can do it like:

```
Process.Start(txtpath.Text);
```

and if the path is without executable name then you will have to write like:

```
Process.Start(txtpath.Text+"\launcher.exe");
```

or more better is to use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(txtpath.Text,"launcher.exe"));
```

and for able to use `Path` class, you would need to add using `System.IO` in the usings of your class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since the 'fdb' doesn't exist in the code below, would that effect it?

Comment: i noticed that, you would need to use `textpath` as you have the value in it's `Text` property

Comment: I now have an issue with 'Path' not existing in the current context.

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: you need to have `using System.IO` on the top of the class